# Visual studio 22 slow Build time with .net core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, msbuild, asp.net-core-6.0

after migration from .net core 2.1 to .net core 6.0, the build time became slow,takes about 1:30 (1 minute and 30 seconds) . by using MSBuild Log Viewer (https://msbuildlog.com/) the result was that most expensive task is CoreCompile, it takes (1:22) from (1:30)
(can see build logs image below).

and in output window can see the build stuck in

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Roslyn\csc.exe
```

after Determine the most expensive task what is the next step to reduce the build time ?
Any help would be much appreciated.

important notice (the build time for same project using same MSBuild in version .net core 2.1 is ( 16 seconds only ) but after migrate to .net core 6.0 for the project build time is ( 1:30 ))

[image]

Comment: _"after Determine the issue "_ - `Roslyn\csc.exe` looks like compiler itself, so I would not say that you have determined the issue.

Comment: @GuruStron the build time for same project using same MSBuild and compiler in version .net core 2.1 is ( 16 seconds only ) but after migrate to .net core 6.0 for the project build time is ( 1:30 )

Comment: I recommend to create a [mre] and create a bug for [roslyn](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn) team.

Comment: i mean if its compiler issue, so why when build the same project in ( .net core 2.1 version ) the build time is normal ( 16 secons ) , In spite of the both vesions using the same compiler.

Comment: Can you install ProcMon, set a filter for `csc.exe` and compile again?

Comment: For starters try deleting all `bin` and `obj` folders from the solution (or if you use git - commit all changes to the branch and do `git clean -fdx`) and rebuild the solution.

Comment: @GuruStron i really appreciate your recommendations ,  i will try it and inform you, thanks alot

Answer (score 3):

In my [experience](https://m0sa.net/posts/2019-08-roslyn-analyzer-runtime-performance/), a lot of time the slow compilation times are caused by some slow analyzer (even the ones shipped by MS can be slow).

You can get detailed diagnostics about how various analyzers affect your build time by running your build with the `/p:ReportAnalyzer=true` MSBuild property, while logging(via the `/bl` flag) & [viewing](https://msbuildlog.com/) the resulting binlog.

[image]